Losing z-values from RasterLayer objects after stacking
I am using MODIS LST products. I am extracting the DOY from each raster file and attaching it to the respective raster. However, setZ() works correctly but I only get NULL values using getZ() after stacking the rasters.
library(raster)

files <- list.files(pattern = ".tif", full.names = FALSE)
s <- stack()
    
# loop over 8-day files for the year 2002
for (file in files) {
  jdt <- as.numeric(substr(file, 34, 36))
  
  # R uses a 0 based index for dates only 
  # this means it starts counting at 0 rather than 1 when working with dates
  jdt <- as.numeric(jdt - 1) 
  year <- as.numeric(substr(file, 30, 33))
  mydate <- as.Date(jdt, origin = as.Date(as.character(paste(year, "-01", "-01", sep = ""), format = "%Y%m%d")))
  r <- raster(file)
  
  # attach date to respective raster
  ras <- setZ(r, mydate, "time") 
  s <- stack(s, ras)
  
  # Returns NULL
  print(getZ(s)) 
}

What is wrong here?

To construct your date, you could also simply make use of %j (Day of year as decimal number (001–366): For input, 366 is only valid in a leap year.), e.g. strptime("2024009", "%Y%j") |> as.Date(), c.f. ?strptime.

Thanks, strptime() is more handy.

The stack function drops the Z names.
Instead, inside the loop collect up all the Z names and then use setZ on the final stacked-up version of s.
Try this, its untested because I don't have a handy set of TIFFs to try it on, but its indicative...
files<- list.files(pattern = ".tif", full.names = F)
znames = c()
s<-stack()

# loop over 8-day files for the year 2002
for (file in files) { 
  jdt<-as.numeric(substr(file,34,36))
  jdt <- as.numeric(jdt-1) # R uses a 0 based index for dates only # this means it starts counting at 0 rather than 1 when working with dates
  year<-as.numeric(substr(file,30,33))
  mydate<- as.Date(jdt, origin = as.Date(as.character(paste(year,"-01","-01", sep=""),format="%Y%m%d")))
  r<-raster(file)
  znames = c(znames, mydate)
  s<-stack(s,r)

}
s = setZ(s, znames)

(Also you should look into using the terra package for raster handling in R these days if possible)

Thank you. The solution works. One thing that I added, was:
znames = as.Date(c())

Just to provide a supplementary answer (nobody asked for) to showcase how setting the time attribute can be solved with {terra} using some MOD11A2 data acquired via USGS EarthExpolorer:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71

# list relevant files (= 12)
fnames <- list.files(pattern = "hdf$")
fnames
#>  [1] "MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713.hdf"
#>  [2] "MOD11A2.A2024009.h18v03.061.2024022175431.hdf"
#>  [3] "MOD11A2.A2024017.h18v03.061.2024027225326.hdf"
#>  [4] "MOD11A2.A2024025.h18v03.061.2024038085520.hdf"
#>  [5] "MOD11A2.A2024033.h18v03.061.2024044090251.hdf"
#>  [6] "MOD11A2.A2024041.h18v03.061.2024051160436.hdf"
#>  [7] "MOD11A2.A2024049.h18v03.061.2024061082638.hdf"
#>  [8] "MOD11A2.A2024057.h18v03.061.2024066121023.hdf"
#>  [9] "MOD11A2.A2024065.h18v03.061.2024074034931.hdf"
#> [10] "MOD11A2.A2024073.h18v03.061.2024085212529.hdf"
#> [11] "MOD11A2.A2024081.h18v03.061.2024094204824.hdf"
#> [12] "MOD11A2.A2024089.h18v03.061.2024099144930.hdf"

# read data (144 layers, 12 files à 12 layers)
# using multi-band HDF files instead of single-band TIFF here
# is less when using `pattern = "tif$"`
r <- rast(fnames)
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1200, 1200, 144  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 1111951, 5559753, 6671703  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#> sources     : MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:QC_Day  
#>               MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:Day_view_time  
#>               ... and 141 more source(s)
#> varnames    : MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713 
#>               MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713 
#>               MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713 
#>               ...
#> names       : LST_Day_1km, QC_Day, Day_v~_time, Day_v~_angl, LST_N~t_1km, QC_Night, ...

# inspect available layers by name (= 12)
names(r) |> unique()
#>  [1] "LST_Day_1km"      "QC_Day"           "Day_view_time"    "Day_view_angl"   
#>  [5] "LST_Night_1km"    "QC_Night"         "Night_view_time"  "Night_view_angl" 
#>  [9] "Emis_31"          "Emis_32"          "Clear_sky_days"   "Clear_sky_nights"

# subset to "LST_Day_1km", reducing your layers to 12, one per file 
r_sub <- r["LST_Day_1km"]
r_sub
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1200, 1200, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 1111951, 5559753, 6671703  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#> sources     : MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               MOD11A2.A2024009.h18v03.061.2024022175431.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               MOD11A2.A2024017.h18v03.061.2024027225326.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               ... and 9 more source(s)
#> varnames    : MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713 
#>               MOD11A2.A2024009.h18v03.061.2024022175431 
#>               MOD11A2.A2024017.h18v03.061.2024027225326 
#>               ...
#> names       : LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, ...

# set time attribute
time(r_sub) <- substr(fnames, 10, 16) |> strptime("%Y%j") |> as.Date()

# inspect final result with time set
r_sub
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1200, 1200, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 1111951, 5559753, 6671703  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#> sources     : MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               MOD11A2.A2024009.h18v03.061.2024022175431.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               MOD11A2.A2024017.h18v03.061.2024027225326.hdf:MODIS_Grid_8Day_1km_LST:LST_Day_1km  
#>               ... and 9 more source(s)
#> varnames    : MOD11A2.A2024001.h18v03.061.2024011195713 
#>               MOD11A2.A2024009.h18v03.061.2024022175431 
#>               MOD11A2.A2024017.h18v03.061.2024027225326 
#>               ...
#> names       : LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, LST_Day_1km, ... 
#> time (days) : 2024-01-01 to 2024-03-29 

